# Evaluate $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}n^2((1 + \frac{1}{n+1})^{n+1} - (1 + \frac{1}{n})^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Wolfram Alpha says this limit is $e/2$, which I believe plotting the sequence, however I'm struggling to prove this.

I've tried to apply l'Hopital or Cesaro-Stolz to no luck. I suspect I need to cleverly manipulate the binomial expansion, but I just make a mess.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with Taylor Series ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1m\right)^m&=e^{m\log\left(1+\frac1m\right)}\\\\
&=e^{\left(1-\frac1{2m}+\frac1{3n^2}+O\left(\frac1{m^3}\right)\right)}\\\\
&=e\left(1-\frac1{2m}+\frac{11}{24m^2}+O\left(\frac1{m^3}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

Hence, we see that the difference $D_n$ is

$$\begin{align}
D_n&=\left(1+\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\\\\&=e\left(1-\frac1{2(n+1)}+\frac{11}{24(n+1)^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)-e\left(1-\frac1{2n}+\frac{11}{24n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)\right)\\\\
&=\frac{e}{2n^2}+O\left(\frac1{n^3}\right)
\end{align}$$

And you can can finish this up.

Comment: Could you explain the step where $e^{f(m)} = e*g(m)$?

Comment: @Kaind g(m) = exp(f(m)-1)

Comment: @Kaind $e^{a+b}=e^ae^b$.  So, with $a=1$ and $b=-\frac1{2m}+\frac1{3n^2}+O\left(\frac1{m^3}\right)$ we have $$e^{1--\frac1{2m}+\frac1{3n^2}+O\left(\frac1{m^3}\right)}=e\,e^{-\frac1{2m}+\frac1{3n^2}+O\left(\frac1{m^3}\right)}$$Now, expand $,e^{-\frac1{2m}+\frac1{3n^2}+O\left(\frac1{m^3}\right)}$.

Comment: Got it now, my confusion arose from the changed coefficient of $\frac{1}{m^2}$ - turns out it was just taylor series for $e^{-x}$.

Comment: Pleased to hear.  Glad this was useful!

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

Put
$$f(x)=(1+x)^\frac 1x=e^{\frac 1x\ln(1+x)}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{x-(x+1)\ln(x+1)}{x^2(x+1)}f(x)$$

apply MVT at $ [\frac{1}{n+1},\frac 1n]$.

$$n^2(f(\frac{1}{n})-f(\frac{1}{n+1}))=$$
$$n^2(\frac 1n-\frac{1}{n+1})f'(c_n)$$

The limit we look for is exactly
$$\lim_{c\to 0}f'(c)$$

For this, use the second order expansion
$$\ln(1+c)=c-\frac{c^2}{2}+c^2\epsilon(c)$$
to get
$$c-(c+1)\ln(1+c)=-\frac{c^2}{2}(1+\epsilon(c))$$

Comment: Always...very nice your answers.

Comment: @Sebastiano Always happy to read you. Baggio and Paolo Rossi are historic players .Ahhahha.

Comment: @Sebastiano Goodnight friend of Scudetto and serie A.

Comment: Very kind friend good night....and rest....:-)...I hope for the "scudetto" to the Inter :-)

Comment: Wow, I really liked this answer. Could I ask what your thought process was behind this?

Comment: @AnishGupta Hu. Wen you have an expression of the form $ f(A)-f(B) $, you think of MVT and FCL iverpool.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_p=\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)^p\implies \log(a_p)=p\log\left(1+\frac{1}{p}\right)$$ So, by Taylor
$$\log(a_p)=1-\frac{1}{2 p}+\frac{1}{3 p^2}-\frac{1}{4
   p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$
$$a_p=e^{\log(a_p)}=e-\frac{e}{2 p}+\frac{11 e}{24 p^2}-\frac{7 e}{16
   p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$

Apply twice and continue with Taylor series

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{e}{2 n^2}-\frac{17 e}{12 n^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^4}\right)$$
$$n^2(a_{n+1}-a_n)=\frac{e}{2}-\frac{17 e}{12 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$